# What's my Cache::Memcached::Fast $class = shift; for in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
my Cache::Memcached::Fast $class = shift;
```

I've been using `my $class = shift;`,

what's `Cache::Memcached::Fast` here for?

When do we have to prefix variables with package name when declaring?

Answer (score 1):

It's the type. See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html

Comment: Can you provide an example where the type is useful?

Comment: Necessary never, but useful sometimes. http://p3rl.org/typesafety http://p3rl.org/types

Answer (score 1):

> When do we have to prefix variables with package name when declaring?

Never, in modern Perl. Types in `my` are only used with the deprecated [`fields`](http://perldoc.perl.org/fields.html) pragma (e.g, restricted hashes). Don't use them in new code.

Comment: Never? It's extracted from Cache::Memcached::Fast module.

Comment: Which is pretty old. That particular line of code is retained from the original `Cache::Memcached` module, which dates back to 2003.